# is Graph Bipartite / Two-Colorable Union Find

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

I am new to graphs and graph theory. I came across the leetcode question [is Graph Bipartite?](https://leetcode.com/problems/is-graph-bipartite/description/). After some reading, is it said that a graph is Bipartite if and only if it is Two-colorable. I decided to solve this using Union Find but my code doesn't pass all test cases. Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with the code below?

```
package org.code;

public class TwoColorable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] edges = { { 1, 3 }, { 0, 2 }, { 1, 3 }, { 0, 2 } };
        TwoColorable tc = new TwoColorable();
        System.out.println(tc.twoColorable(edges));
    }

    public boolean twoColorable(int[][] edges) {
        int n = edges.length; // # of vertices
        UnionFind uf = new UnionFind(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int[] edge = edges[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < edge.length; j++) {
                if (uf.union(i, edge[j])) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private class UnionFind {
        int[] parent;
        int[] colors;

        public UnionFind(int n) {
            parent = new int[n];
            colors = new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                parent[i] = i; // initially you are your own parent
            }
        }

        public int find(int x) {
            if (parent[x] == x)
                return x;
            return (parent[x]);
        }

        public boolean union(int x, int y) {
            int parentX = find(x);
            int parentY = find(y);
            if (parentX != parentY) {
                // if both are zero then we are free to assign a color
                if (colors[x] == 0 && colors[y] == 0) {
                    colors[x] = 1;
                    colors[y] = 2;
                    // still have to union them
                    parent[parentY] = parentX;
                    return true;
                }
                // if x is 0 and the colors don't match or Y has not been
                // assigned a color
                else if (colors[x] != 0 && colors[y] == 0) {
                    if (colors[x] == 1) {
                        colors[y] = 2;
                    } else {
                        colors[y] = 1;
                    }
                    // still have to union them
                    parent[parentY] = parentX;
                    return true;
                } else if (colors[x] == 0 && colors[y] != 0) {
                    if (colors[y] == 1) {
                        colors[x] = 2;
                    } else {
                        colors[x] = 1;
                    }
                    // still have to union them
                    parent[parentY] = parentX;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    if (colors[x] != colors[y]) {
                        parent[parentY] = parentX;
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
            // here if they have the same parent, then you have to check
            // if their colors are different
            else {
                return colors[x] == colors[y] ? false : true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would this code work? Can you explain your thinking?

Comment: My thinking was as follows as I encounter an edge I check the vertices for color disparity. If they are unassigned or one vertex has a color and another unassigned, I would connect them and continue in this manner until either the colors of both vertices were the same or the edges were connected but had the same color

Comment: If you have an adjacency-list graph, then you should normally use BFS to solve this problem -- the graph is bipartite unless there is an edge between vertices at the same level.  If you only have an edge list, then you can use union-find, modified so that the links keep track of whether the parent set must be the same or different color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This algorithm will not work. Consider this graph:

[image]

...represented with `{{3},{2,4},{1},{0,4},{1,3}}`.

Then this is the sequence of actions your code will take:

```
union(0, 3)
  color[0] := 1
  color[3] := 2
union(1, 2)
  color[1] := 1
  color[2] := 2
```

At this point we can see the assignment of colors of the top nodes and bottom nodes is not compatible, but the algorithm has not detected any problem yet:

[image]

so it continues:

```
union(1, 4)
  color[4] := 2
union(2, 1)
  already in same group. colors are different, so OK
union(3, 0)
  already in same group. colors are different, so OK
```

We have this coloring now:

[image]

Then the problematic edge is analysed:

```
union(3, 4)
  colors are the same, so PROBLEM
```

The problem is that this algorithm can assign colors to nodes that are "far" from each other, which means that these colorings can never be considered final, yet the algorithm has no way to backtrack on its earlier assigned colors to still make it work.

You'll have to come up with a different algorithm.

---

Unrelated, but your `find` function is not correct. It is supposed to return the "root" of the disjoint set, but `return (parent[x])` is not guaranteeing that. You could make a recursive call of `find`. Still, this would not matter, as the algorithm is not suited for this problem.

---

A more efficient algorithm will take a node and color it, and then repeat the same for its neighbors but with the opposite color. If then there is a collision of incompatible colors, you can conclude the graph is not bipartite. Repeat this check for each disconnected component of the graph.

Spoiler solution:

> `class Solution {
>      public boolean isBipartite(int[][] graph) {
>          int[] colors = new int[graph.length];
>
>          for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
>              if (colors[i] == 0) { // at graph component
>                  if (!dfs(graph, colors, i, 1)) return false;
>              }
>          }
>          return true;
>      }
>
>      private boolean dfs(int[][] edges, int[] colors, int i, int color) {
>          if (colors[i] != 0) return colors[i] == color;
>          colors[i] = color; // visit
>          for (int j = 0; j < edges[i].length; j++) {
>              if (!dfs(edges, colors, edges[i][j], 3 - color)) return false;
>          }
>          return true;
>      }
>  }`

Comment: Just a small question to the backtracking comment. Since there are 2 colors is it necessary to back track because I think I would have reached the same state with the previous color or maybe I need to think about this some more.

Comment: It is not necessary if you use a different algorithm, but with the current algorithm you risk that you are assigning colors to nodes that are far from eachother, like in two separate "corners" of the graph. And then the colored parts will eventually "meet" where the inconsistency surfaces, and then one of the two colored parts with previously assigned colors needs to toggle all its colors to make them compatible with the other part.

Comment: Ok thank you. I shall try a regular depth first search and see how that pans out.

Comment: I was able to solve this using a simple dfs approach. Thanks